# Not able to extract keys in a amzon S3 bucket having some prefix using python boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to get list of keys with some prefix in amazon s3 bucket. I followed the steps shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/GetAllKeys) But still i am get keys available in that bucket with that prefix. Below is the code i tried.

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(anon=True)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('aws-publicdatasets')
for each_rs in self.bucket.list(prefix="/project_prefix/prefx_key2/prefix_key3/"):
    print each_rs.name
```

But the below code is working fine to retrieve all the keys in aws puvlic data sets

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(anon=True)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('aws-publicdatasets')
for each_rs in self.bucket.list():
    print each_rs.name
```

I tried with get_all_keys(prefix="/project_prefix/prefx_key2/prefix_key3/") but still no luck. Is there any other way to get list of keys having given prefix?

Comment: Had that issue as well and didn't solve it yet.  It wasn't really necessary for me back then, so I didn't pursuit it any longer, but I'd be interested in an answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

you get the keys only for a defined prefix. Try this:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3(anon=True)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('aws-publicdatasets')
list = bucket.list("common-crawl/crawl-001/2008/08/22/28")
for key in list:
    print key.name
```

Comment: Thank, Thats working.. but i didn't understand what is the error in my code. I don't think giving prefix= in list is mistake. Is there any other point i am missng

Comment: prefix= is okay, but the error is the first slash in `prefix="/..."`